# TypeScript compiler very slow (6-10s)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular

I'm learning Angular 2 in typescript, however my compiler's watch mode runs very slowly, like every 6-10 sec which is a bit much if I want to see the change.

Is there any way to speed to this up to <1s?

**TSC version: 1.8.10**

**NPM version: 2.11.3**

Comment: What version of node do you have?